# Testing window.location.origin polyfill

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, jsdom, polyfills

I'd like to write a test to prove a polyfill works. I'm using `mocha`, `chai`, and `jsdom`. `jsdom` exposes `window.location.origin` as a readonly property so I can't force the polyfill to be used (throws `TypeError: Cannot set property origin of [object Object] which has only a getter` when attempting to set `global.window.location.origin = null`;

polyfill:

```
export default function polyfills () {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    // http://tosbourn.com/a-fix-for-window-location-origin-in-internet-explorer/
    if (!window.location.origin) {
        let loc = window.location,
            port = loc.port ? `:${loc.port}` : '';

        loc.origin = `${loc.protocol}//${loc.hostname}${port}`;
    }
}
```

jsdom setup:

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';

global.document = jsdom.jsdom(
    '<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>',
    {
        url: 'https://www.google.com/#q=testing+polyfills'
    }
);

global.window = document.defaultView;
global.navigator = window.navigator;
```

test:

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import polyfills from '../path/to/polyfills';

describe('the polyfill function', function () {
    before(() => {
        delete global.window.location.origin;

        // polyfills(); // test still passes when this is commented out
    });

    it('correctly exposes the window.location.origin property', () => {
        expect(global.window.location.origin).to.equal('https://google.com');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Object.defineProperty` worked:

```
describe('The polyfill function', function () {
    let loc;

    before(() => {
        loc = global.window.location;

        Object.defineProperty(loc, 'origin', {
            value: null,
            writable: true
        });

        polyfills();
    });

    it('correctly polyfills window.location.origin', () => {
        expect(loc.origin).to.equal('https://google.com');
    });
});
```